# Preciso listar dados do Banco, cada um num componente, caso exista. em C# .NET Visual Studio

Tags: c#

Em C#, visual Studio.
olá sou novato e venho buscar ajuda, Gostaria de exibir em um componente, pode ser no textBox, Panel ou label os dados da tabela 'OCUPACOES'. vou tentar explicar:

Eu tenho uma tabela chamada 'OCUPACOES' onde tenho os campos: ID, QUARTO,DATA, HOSPEDE. Quando faço uma reserva, os campos: ID, QUARTO,DATA, HOSPEDE recebe os respectivos valores. Quando faço o check-Out, os campos: ID, QUARTO,DATA, HOSPEDE ficam em branco, indicando que não há reservas.
O que eu Gostaria é de exibir o campo QUARTO em um componente, caso exista valor. Se estiver em branco não exibir ou ficar verde. Alguém tem como me passar alguma orientação? já consigo lista numa grid, e contar os elementos e até pegar o campo com o Reader, mas pega apenas um dado.

para listar: "SELECT * FROM ocupacoes ORDER BY quarto asc";
para verificar: cmdVerificar = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM quartos WHERE quarto = @quarto", con.con);

ajude-me

Answer (score 0):

Sempre que quer ler um novo dado é necessário usar a função Reader.Read()
Recomendo então usar o seguinte excerto que verifica se o reader tem dados e procede em criar um while que lê linha a linha:

```
if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // ATUALIZAR A DATAGRID AQUI
            }
        }
```

Comment: Eu consegui resolver este caso. Agora o problema é outro. Meu if (QuartoOcupado == "01") fico limitado a quantidade quarto "01", "02"... preciso de um  if (QuartoOcupado == QuartoCadastrado). onde busco os quarto da tabela 'Quartos'. alguma sugestão?